# shell script remove file after move

Tags: shell

Since in the control file I have to provide a name (hard-coded) I need to rename my file and then remove it. Yet it does not work..it returns code 2. Any suggestions?

```
JALON_03(){

mv $FIC_INPUT AlimentationFichier.data
sqlldr $BDD_USR/$BDD_PWD@$BDD_STR control=$FIC_CTL
RETCODE=$?

        if [ $RETCODE -ne 0 ]; then
                               echo $RETCODE "[ERR] `date '+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'` Erreur supprimer le fichier!">>$FIC_LOG
                    exit 2;
                    fi

rm AlimentationFichier.data
RETCODE=$?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the script will exit after the error message is written to the Logfile? Then please check if your sqlldr-call is okay.